# Windows Raster Fonts Encoding Error

Tags: windows, macos, unicode, fonts, cmd

I'm writing an interpreter and I have come across a peculiar problem involving character sets. ( I think ).

When I create a file on my Mac called, `hello.rd` and I run the command;

```
file -I hello.rd
```

I get this output:

```
hello.rd: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

That shows me the file is UTF-8 which it should be. The source file looks like this;

```
print "Hello World á"
```

And the output in the terminal is:

```
Hello World á
```

This is all the way I want / expect it to be. The problem arises when I execute the code on Windows. When I execute the same code on Windows I get this output:
[image: Output on Windows]

As you can see the á isn't output correctly. I changed the codepage to 65001 and it made no difference, but when I used the Lucida Console font, the characters displayed correctly. But what I can't understand is, why I can type the letter `á` in the terminal using my keyboard and it displays, but it won't display from my files.

So what I did next was I created a file on my Windows PC called `test123.rd` and saved this text in it:

```
print "Hello World á ã ß"
```

When I execute that on my Mac I get the incorrect output this time, I get:

```
Hello World ? ? ?
```

And on my PC I still get the incorrect output, I get this:
[image: Second Windows Output]

I used the `file -I` command on my Mac on the file `test123.rd` and I got this output:

```
test123.rd: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I assume since the character set in the `test123.rd` file isn't UTF-8, is why the file `test123.rd` is displaying incorrectly on OSX but I don't understand why it's displaying incorrectly on Windows as well.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem, without changing the font of the Windows CMD?

Comment: Your Windows console is probably using a third encoding.

Comment: @SLaks Is there any way to determine which encoding it's using?

Comment: I's 8 bit font. There is a command line switch to use 16 bit unicode.

Comment: @D.Ddgg do you mean the raster fonts are 8 bit fonts? Also do you know how I can change them to 16 bit?

Answer (score 1):

Type `cmd /?` to see how to switch unicode on, then choose a unicode font. Also see `chcp /?`.